# virtualenvwrapper Error: The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to set up virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper on Ubuntuo 18.04, but when I try to run `mkvirtualenv temp` I get an error from virtualenvwrapper: `The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist`.

The relevant lines from .bashrc are:

```
147 # virtualenvwrapper variables
148 export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
149 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
150 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv
151 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

If I run `mkvirtualenv temp --python=python3`, the environment is created as expected and works fine but I get the message `Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3` which tells me that .bashrc line 149 is correctly setting the variable.

The confusion I have is that I don't use Python2. I know that it is installed on the OS but is the default version for virtualenvwrapper Python 2.x? Even if it was I believe that lines 149 and 150 in .bashrc override this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the python version you want to use

```
mkvirtualenv venv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```